# Angularjs not working with cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I am using `cordova` to develop an android application and try `angularjs` with it. When I try the application with browser its working but when I try the application on the android emulator I am only getting **Connecting to Device**.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady,false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['HelloWorld']);
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
app.initialize();

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        <h1 ng-bind="name">Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:10px;">
            <button ng-click="process()">Click Here</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /**
    *  Module
    *
    * Description
    */
    angular.module('HelloWorld', []).controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.name = "Welcome TO Cordova";

        $scope.process = function(){
            $scope.name = "Welcome Mr. Ddeveloper";
        }
    }])
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: did you tried to use angularjs creating a module and binding it with ng-app ?

I can see that your code is somewhere messy with cordova events. Why don't you use angular outside?

Comment: You means to say that initialize angular scope outside the deviceready event

Comment: yep, just create a normal angularjs app and then do what you must with cordova... I tried once, it should work flawlessy

Comment: Removed all javascript code and added  ng-app="HelloWorld" to the <html> but still same problem works in browser not in emulator

Comment: tried in real phone?

Comment: Yes i  tried it in real phone and its working out there. But why its not working in the emulator

Comment: it's an emulator, and is projected to work with the standard android ADK, cordova does some magic and this might be too much for your emulator.
Maybe wrong version? I won't put too much effort in this, instead you can try something like GapDebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error while executing the above snippet:

1. Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback
2. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Try the following way:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>

    </head>
   <body>
    <div class="app" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
        <h1 ng-bind="name">Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:10px;">
            <button ng-click="process()">Click Here</button>
        </div>
    </div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/homeController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In homeController.js

```
angular.module('HelloWorld', []).controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.name = "Welcome TO Cordova";

        $scope.process = function(){
            $scope.name = "Welcome Mr. Ddeveloper";
        }
    }])
```